# How to remove shadow from image generated using ImageRenderer?

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I am trying to render a cover image that consist of a color background with a title and border on top. When I render the image from a SwiftUI view using ImageRender the title and border have a strange shadow around them. This shadow is not present on the SwiftUI view. Is there a way to fix this? I want the title and border to look as if they are lying flat against the background.

Here is the code:

```
@MainActor func renderCover() {
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: coverRenderView)
        renderer.scale = 6.0
        if let uiImage = renderer.uiImage {
            cover = uiImage
        }
    }

private var coverRenderView: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color.gradient)
            CoverDetailsView(title: title, detailColor: detailColor, showBorder: true, showTitle: true)
        }
        .thumbnail(size: .largeThumbnail)
    }

struct CoverDetailsView: View {
    var title: String
    var detailColor: Color
    var showBorder: Bool
    var showTitle: Bool
    @State private var size: CGSize = .largeThumbnail
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showBorder {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(detailColor, lineWidth: 2)
                    .padding(size.width*0.06)
            }
            if showTitle {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.robotoSlab(size: 32, weight: .medium))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(detailColor)
                    .padding(size.width*0.15)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: -75)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the images I am getting:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried this in a Playground where I can quick-view the resulting uiImage and cannot see this behaviour. Are you sure this is happening in the renderer? Or might we see some compression artefacts instead of shadows here, maybe from saving the results to a JPG?

Comment: I also wondered if those were compression artifacts.

Comment: I am saving these as a .png when I upload them to the server. On the view where they can be created I am displaying them as Image(uiImage: cover) and they still have the same issue. That is where my screenshots are from.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Jerrot is right, those are JPEG Compression artifacts.

If you zoom in it has the "swarm of mosquitoes" look that I associate with low quality JPEG compression. Here is a closeup of a portion of one of your images:

[image]

Note the blocky, blotchy look of the halos around high-contrast borders. That looks like JPEG compression artifacts to me.

Try saving your images as PNGs instead of JPEGs and I bet that halo effect goes away

Comment: I am saving these as a .png when I upload them to the server. On the view where they can be created I am displaying them as Image(uiImage: cover) and they still have the same issue. That is where my screenshots are from.